# Best method for approximating rigid body rotation equations

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to numerically approximate the solution to the rigid body rotation problem, given by the equations
$$I_1u_1^\prime=(I_2-I_3)u_2u_3$$
$$I_2u_2^\prime=(I_3-I_1)u_3u_1$$
$$I_3u_3^\prime=(I_1-I_2)u_1u_2$$
Where $I_n$ is the n-th moment of inertia.

Differentiating the equations, it follows that  one can express
$$\epsilon^{\prime\prime} = \frac{(I_3-I_1)(I_1-I_2)}{I_2I_3}u_1^2\epsilon $$
Et cetera, thus the equation is a harmonic oscillator if the constant is negative, or a harmonic repulsor if it is positive, and trivially the axis with the intermediate moment is the unstable one, showing an exponential growth.

My question is: can I use an explicit method for the integration or do I have to use an A-stable/L-stable (implicit) method?

Comment: Comment for others reading: despite the votes to close, I don't see why this is off-topic for MathOverflow

Comment: The solutions stay bounded since $I_1 u_1^2 + I_2 u_2^2 + I_3 u_3^2$ is constant.  I don't see why this would be very difficult for any of the standard numerical methods.

Comment: If you're concerned about conserving $I_1 u_1^2 + I_2 u_2^2 + I_3 u_3^2$ (which won't stay quite constant in most numerical methods) over long times, you might convert $[\sqrt{I_1} u_1, \sqrt{I_2} u_2, \sqrt{I_3} u_3]$ to spherical coordinates, and solve a system of two equations in $\theta, \phi$ with the radial coordinate constant.